# new Date() returns local time instead of UTC

Tags: android

If i run

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date())
```

in an app in an android device emulator whose timezone is set to IST(GMT + 05:30), it gives me the local time. If i keep changing the timezone in the phone settings and run it, i will keep getting the appropriate local time.

But `Date()` is supposed to return UTC time, not timezone specific local time. Why is it not happening?

I can get the UTC( actually GMT) time if i run

```
select datetime('now')
```

in the SQLite database within the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` defaults to the current timezone.

Call `setTimeZone()` on the formatter to make it format to some other timezone.

The internal representation of `Date` is in UTC.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> each SimpleDateFormat instance has a TimeZone. This is because it's called upon to format instances of Date, which represents an absolute time in UTC. That is, Date does not carry time zone information. By default, SimpleDateFormat will use the system's default time zone.

Comment: do you think it's possible to do a similar formatting without applying a timezone? Hoping to store the UTC time as text in the SQLite database.

Comment: You can call `formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))` to set it to UTC.